# Translating WinForms Drawing Code to Xamarin.Forms Without SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I came across the following WinForms drawing code that I need to adapt for use in a Xamarin.Forms project. However, the code is originally written within the SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs event handler in a SKCanvasView. I want to use this code outside of that event handler and apply the drawing to a different context or control.

```
using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms;

// In your Page or ContentView class
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    SKCanvasView canvasView;

    public MyPage()
    {
        canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
        canvasView.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface;

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = { canvasView }
        };
    }

    private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
        SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();

        using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint())
        {
            paint.IsAntialias = true;
            paint.FilterQuality = SKFilterQuality.High;

            // Perform your drawing here using SKCanvas methods

            // Example:
            paint.Color = SKColors.Red;
            canvas.DrawRect(new SKRect(0, 0, info.Width, info.Height), paint);

            // Draw other shapes, images, etc.

            // Make sure to handle scaling and transformations appropriately
            canvas.Scale(2.0f, 2.0f); // Example scaling
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that Xamarin.Forms uses SkiaSharp for graphics, and I have added the necessary NuGet package. However, I'm unsure how to translate this code to work in a different context, for example, within a method or another event in Xamarin.Forms.

If anyone could provide guidance on how to adapt this WinForms drawing code for use in Xamarin.Forms without relying on the SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs event, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please provide a **specific example** of the "different context" you need to apply this to that would not involve the `PaintSurface` event

Comment: For example after adding an `ImageButton` to my stacklayout and need to draw the new image with previous images into the source of a single `Image` property.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/drawing